# Optional pipping to shell script

Tags: pipe, sh, stdin

I want to get the content of stdin in a variable only if something was pipped to the script, the code I'm using is:

```
input=$(cat)
echo "$@ $input"
```

Doing `echo 'something' | ./script` works as expected, but not pipping anything just makes the script waiting indefinitely for input. How do I ignore empty stdin?

Comment: So to summarize your requirement? You want to store the contents of `stdin` only if your script is not receiving from a pipe-line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing if something was passed to stdin like this before trying to set a variable seems to solve the problem:

```
if ! [ -t 0 ]; then
    input=$(cat)
fi
```